# Namespaces for functions and variables in Swift

Tags: swift

If you run this code, the variable f seems to shadow the function f. Is there anyway to reach the function f?

```
func f (a:Int)->Int{
   return a + 43
}

var f = {(a:Int) in a + 42}

var z = f(1)
println(z)
```

Comment: Why you try to do that? aka name both with the same name

Comment: I don't believe there is a way, and I would consider this a defect in the compiler. This should be an error. I recommend opening a radar about that. What's interesting is that it doesn't matter which is declared first. The var always wins.

Comment: I'll add a radar for it.

Comment: That's an interesting edge case.  In other languages like C, you can re-use symbol names in different contexts, but with closures like this, it gets more complicated.  What did they say about it?

Comment: Since you're running this in the REPL by the looks of it, you can reference earlier work by printing it. `func f ...`; `f`; `> $R0: (Int) -> Int`; `$R0(1)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.

In Swift, function declarations are simply shortcuts for what you did with that closure + variable thing. That is, function names are essentially constants and should always be viewed as such (you can even pass around the function name, without brackets, as a reference).

What you're doing is you're redeclaring the name f to the variable closure. It seems Swift has a compiler issue not complaining about this. However, this problem would never occur in good code, so it's not a real problem.

It can be a bit confusing, though.